# Optimize simple comparison with zero for performance

Tags: c++, if-statement, optimization, conditional-statements, bitwise-operators

I have a bottleneck (about 20% CPU time) in my code which is in following if statement:

```
if (a == 0) { // here
    ...
}
```

where `a` is a `uint8_t`, so a number from 0 to 255.

Are there any low level optimizations to make it faster?
I thought about using bitwise NOR `(~(a| 0))`, but that would work only if `a` was a 1-bit, right?

Just in case: I don't care about code readability in this particular case.

Comment: You need to show the code around it. There's no way to optimize an if-statement _by itself_. Context matters.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/branch-and-loop-reorganization-to-prevent-mispredicts

Comment: @zenith that's exactly what I was interested in - optimizing the statement itself, by rewriting it with bitwise operators for example (that should work faster, right?)

Comment: Why would something like that make it work faster? Every half-decent compiler is able to make such optimizations by itself.

Comment: Also, if `a` is not a local variable, consider making it local. That could be a bottleneck (but should not with a decent compiler with optimizations turned on).

Comment: it should go without saying, but just to be clear: you are compiling with appropriate optimizations enable, right?

Comment: @bolov I'm using Visual Studio. I've went through settings, optimization was set to /O2. After putting it to /Ox, this if statement is still 20-something percent of computing time, but overall time went down by a second. Thanks for reminding this!

Comment: @IļjaGubins This isn't the kind of thing you can optimize by itself. What else could you possibly do that you haven't already done? You've specified precisely and clearly what you want in the simplest imaginable way. What else could help the compiler build better code? The performance issue likely has to do with what has to happen to get `a`'s value or branch prediction, or other things we can't tell from just this bit. (You haven't even told us whether the branch is almost always taken, almost never taken, random, follows a pattern, or anything else. So on what basis could we optimize it?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I realize that it is possible to lower that bottleneck simply by calling that if statement less, but I was wondering specially about if there is anything possible about that `if`. I've just checked this, around 90% of all times it goes inside that `if`. Is there anything that can be done with this? I know that GCC has `expect`, but from what I've found, Visual Studio compiler doesn't support this.

Comment: @IļjaGubins It depends what's inside the `if`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless your compiler is garbage, there is nothing you can do to speed up integer comparison.

However, it is possible that the bottleneck you observe is not really the comparison itself, but rather the result of unlucky branch prediction.

There are two ways of getting around this:

If *"to branch or not to branch"* follows a pattern, move this last second decision further up in your program logic where you can use the pattern, just don't branch in your hot function. This might require serious thinking. A hacky way to find out whether you have patterns: Print `1` if you branch and `0` else for enough calls, Zip is up and see whether the resulting archive gets much smaller (in bits) than the number of values you printed. (Of course there are also smart formulas for that if you like it more theoretical.)

If you choose one branch over the other most of the time, you can tell the compiler which branch is the likely one. With gcc, checkout `__builtin_expect`, for other compilers, read the manual.

**Important for both solutions:** You will need to measure whether that actually helped. Especially the second one will not be magically be better, it might even make things much worse.

Comment: If there is only one `if`, without `else`, does that still create branches? And is there any chance to work around it?

Comment: @yes ofc there are branches: there are 2 paths: one if cond is true, one if cond if false (on this path you skip the `then` part of `if`)

Comment: @IļjaGubins Of course an `if` without `else` is a branch, you either execute the code in the `if` or you don't. *" And is there any chance to work around it?"* Depends on your code and program logic, if you can make the decision earlier, it might help.

Comment: @BaummitAugen I've just checked, around 90% of times it goes inside that if statement. Thanks for `__builtin_expect`, but I'd like to use Visual Studio built-in compiler, which from I've seen, doesn't have this.

Comment: @IļjaGubins [This thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2dbdca4d-c0c0-40a3-993b-dc78817be26e/branch-hints?forum=vclanguage) says that PGO might do the right thing for you, but I have no experience with Microsoft compilers.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thank you! Using PGO trimmed another second off total time running!